# TPanel + TImage array

Tags: delphi

Как сделать расстояние между края картинки и панели одинаковыми во всех ячейках? У меня почему-то идет смещение картинок внутри панели.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  X, Y: Integer;
  PanelArray: Array [1 .. 5, 1 .. 5] of TPanel;
  ImgArray: Array [1 .. 5, 1 .. 5] of TImage;
begin
  for Y := 1 to 5 do
    for X := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      PanelArray[X, Y] := TPanel.Create(Self);
      PanelArray[X, Y].Parent := Self;
      PanelArray[X, Y].Color := clBtnFace;
      PanelArray[X, Y].BevelInner := bvNone;
      PanelArray[X, Y].BevelKind := bkNone;
      PanelArray[X, Y].BevelOuter := bvRaised;
      PanelArray[X, Y].Left := X * 170 - 150;  // расстояние между панелями по горизонтали
      PanelArray[X, Y].Top := Y * 170 - 150;  // расстояние между панелями по вертикали
      PanelArray[X, Y].Width := 150;    // ширина панели
      PanelArray[X, Y].Height := 155;   // высота панели

      ImgArray[X, Y] := TImage.Create(PanelArray[X, Y]);
      ImgArray[X, Y].Parent := PanelArray[X, Y];
      ImgArray[X, Y].Left := x * 10 - 8;
      ImgArray[X, Y].Top := y * 10 - 8;
      ImgArray[X, Y].Width := 100;
      ImgArray[X, Y].Height := 100;
      ImgArray[X, Y].Picture.LoadFromFile(IntToStr(x) + '.bmp');
    end;
end;
```

Comment: тот момент, когда стоило применить фрейм

Comment: еще есть `TGridPanel`

Answer (score 5):

```
PanelArray[X, Y].Width  := 150;    // ширина панели
PanelArray[X, Y].Height := 150;   // высота панели
```

У Вас одна картинка на панели. Ее положение не будет зависеть от счетчиков циклов.

```
ImgArray[X, Y].Left := 2;
ImgArray[X, Y].Top  := 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

@Igor полностью прав. Могу дополнить только что можно еще так:

```
...
ImgArray[X, Y].Align := alClient;

//настройка отступов если нужно
ImgArray[X, Y].AlignWithMargins := True;
ImgArray[X, Y].Margins.Left := 2;
ImgArray[X, Y].Margins.Top := 2;
ImgArray[X, Y].Margins.Bottom := 0;
ImgArray[X, Y].Margins.Right := 0;
...
```

В таком случае не будет проблем с `High Dpi`.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!

Comment: Возник следующий вопрос как теперь подгрузить картинки из базы, вернее путь к картинкам хранятся в таблице, у меня почему то последнюю картинку выводит?

Comment: Это уже совсем другой вопрос. Возможно вы открываете `DataSet`/`Query` и не перебираете записи `ds.First` `ds.Next`.